# TableViews not working with TabBarController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I have an app with a `tableView`. I decided to add more screens with other `tableViews`, so I added a `tabBarController` programatically. Now I get a *found nil error* on these lines:

```
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
```

If I remove them, the `tableView` doesn't load.  Do you know what I might be doing wrong?

I added a `tabBarController` on main storyboard an linked it to the swift file, but it also doesn't work.

```
        class SecondVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

        var SoundsClasss = [SoundsClass]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         let p1 = SoundsClass(imageURL: "sound 01", audioURL: "01", videoTitle: "1", duration: 100)
         let p2 = SoundsClass(imageURL: "sound 01", audioURL: "02", videoTitle: "2", duration: 100)

         SoundsClasss.append(p1)
         SoundsClasss.append(p2)

         tableView.delegate = self
         tableView.dataSource = self

         }
```

The code for the `TabBarController`. Do I have to change anything here to specify that the view is a `tableView`?

```
        class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

             override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()

                 tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
                 setupTabBar()

                }

             func setupTabBar(){

              let FirstController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainVC())
              let SecondController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SecondVC()) 
              let ThirdController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ThirdVC())

              viewControllers = [FirstController, SecondController,ThirdController]

              guard let items = tabBar.items else { return }        
              for item in items {
                    item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 0, bottom: -4, right: 0)
                   }
                }

             }
```

Comment: What's nil, the `tableView` variable?

Comment: it might be an invalid outlet for table view, but any way please upload your code and share it with us, to easily detect the problem

Comment: To add the tab bar controller, you should have selected your `SecondVC` in the Storyboard and selected **Editor->Embed In->Tab Bar Controller**.

Comment: How do you create an instance of `SecondVC`?

Comment: Yes, the tableview is nil. tableView UITableView? nil. 
 This is the error I get: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
2019-05-25 21:41:27.889311+0900 Sounds[16006:583763] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in class named `SecondVC` you have an outlet reference for your UITableView instance this means you create your table view in Stroyboard, so you can not create the view controller using the initializer you should use

```
UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryBoardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewcontrollerID")
```

the setupTabBar function should be as the following

```
 func setupTabBar(){

    let vc1 = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryBoardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourFirstViewcontrollerID")
    let vc2 = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryBoardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourSecondViewcontrollerID")
    let vc3 = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryBoardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourThirdViewcontrollerID")

    let FirstController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)
    let SecondController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc2)
    let ThirdController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc3)

    viewControllers = [FirstController, SecondController,ThirdController]

    guard let items = tabBar.items else { return }
    for item in items {
        item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 0, bottom: -4, right: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! this is correct. I didn't know how to initialize it and this solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

You're using `SecondVC()` to create your controller.  That does not reference the storyboard so it does not set up any outlets.

You need to either build your view controller hierarchy in the storyboard and let it load by default or else get your controllers from the storyboard before adding them to the navigation controllers.

See documentation for:

```
func instantiateViewController(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UIViewController
```